# Creating Observable from Object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

How I can create an Observable from this object?

```
this.localStorage.getItem('user').subscribe((user) => {
      if (user != null) {
        console.log(user);
        console.log('User existiert!');

        // Create Observable
        this.data = new Observable((observer: any) => {
          observer.next(user);
          observer.complete();
        });

        return this.data;

      }
    });
```

The user object looks like this:

[image]

I wrote this into a service, but subscribing from components is not working. What´s the issue?

Comment: You already have an observable, that's what you're subscribing to. It's unclear what's *"not working"*; give a [mcve].

Comment: Localstorage serializes your data, so you can only store json objects and not actual  objects.

Comment: I´m using this plugin as async local storage: https://github.com/cyrilletuzi/angular-async-local-storage Will be possible to return an Observable that can be subscribed from components?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return an observable in your service method, and have the components call that method to get the observable.

Also as jonrsharpe already mentioned, you don't need to create another observable. Just use the map/tap operator if you want to do transformations on your data or use `console.log`.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage@6';

class Service {

  constructor(private localStorage: LocalStorage) {}

  // this is the naive approach
  getUser() {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      this.localStorage.getItem('user').subscribe((user) => {
        if (user != null) {
          console.log(user);
          console.log('User existiert!'); 
        }
        observer.next(user);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }

  // this is a better approach
  getUser() {
    return this.localStorage.getItem('user').pipe(
      map((user) => {
        if (user != null) {
          console.log(user);
          console.log('User existiert!');
        }
        return user
      }),
    );
  }
}
```